# Configure environment specific parameters in SSIS Catalog

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a SSIS package deployed to SSISDB. In the SSIS package, I have Project level properties to store, for example, database password. I set those properties to Sensitive but then it requires to enter them each time I run the package. I checked the "Configure" option in SSISDB for that package, but I cannot see the option to link the Project specific parameters in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create "environment variables" in the SSIS Catalog:

[Setup Environment Variables in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4810/setup-environment-variables-in-sql-server-integration-services/)

Or you can config the step on the job that runs the package and change the parameter value.